# Howto break on UnitTesting.Assert.AreEqual?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Standard behavior of assertion in a VS UnitTest project is to just tell me that a test has failed on a specific line.

Sometimes however it would be convenient, if I could break when such an assertion fails. Because just setting a breakpoint on that line breaks also for not failing testcases. If I could break on assertion failing, I could see immediately which testcase is failing.

How can I temporarily tell VS to break, when assertion fails?

E.g. I have many loops in the following way in my unit tests and want to know which iteration is failing:

```
foreach(var testcase in testcases)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(testcase.ExpectedOutputData, FuncionUnderTest(testcase.InputData));
}
```

Comment: Maybe nUnit's testcases are what you want? They allow you to debug one-by-one.

Comment: I usually start all the tests in debug mode, when I work with VS. The debugger breaks on any exceptions if there are some. This requires that you don't set any breakpoints. Not a real solution, therefore just a comment to think about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a conditional breakpoint, and give it the logical negative of the assertion's check.

Personally, I think breakpoints are seriously underused as nothing more than a 'break at this point' tool- They're very versatile, and can easily be used instead of `Console.WriteLine` for showing debug output without actually modifying the code, as well as only breaking if an assertion would fail.

They do tend to cause a bit of a performance hit if overused this way though, but that's rarely a problem running unit tests.

Comment: +1 was just looking for the example code to go with an answer like this, beat me to it ;)

editing this in to your answer might help

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: It might just be a matter of preference (or I'm missing something really useful), but I've never used that. I've always felt that the whole point of breakpoints is that you DON'T need to modify your actual source for the sake of debugging.

Comment: The majority of the time when you want to always stop there its generally fine to just have them on the margin, but sometimes if it iterates say 1000 times you dont want to press f5 999 times to get the 1000th one, thats when a programattic breakpoint can help speed up your development, in my experience anyway

Comment: That's where I'd use the 'Hit Count' setting on a breakpoint. You can specifically set it to only break on the 1000th time it passes it. You can even set it to break when the hit count is a multiple of a number, such as every 10th time it would hit.

Comment: I apologise, i was unaware of this, i have learnt something new today, thankyou

Comment: Hey, don't apologise- It's always worth considering all the options, and there's a reason the programmatic method exists. For example, the annoying thing I find about breakpoints is that it's far too easy to accidentally delete one with a careless click, which means you've got to set up all of it's properties again. I've been tempted to use the `Debugger` stuff for that reason alone, at points where I'm using a breakpoint a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Without having too much knowledge of how you're constructing your unit tests, it seems to me that if you are struggling to see which assertion is causing your unit test to fail, then perhaps you are testing too much in your individual tests? Unit tests should be as atomic as possible to negate against precisely this issue. If you can break your tests up, even down to having a single assertion within a single test, it will be much easier to work out which test is failing. I would certainly advocate that over writing breakpoint-specific code into your unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you use nUnit you can have this that allows you to debug separately:

```
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(1)]
public void NunitTestCases(int expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected,0);
}
```

I guess you can always do this though:

```
[Test]
public void BreakTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        bool condition = i == 0;
        if(!condition)
            Debugger.Break();
        Assert.IsTrue(condition);
    }
}
```